# Why does the Synthetic Control Method Package in Python assign equal weights to all potential controls instead of optimising?

Tags: python

It's my first time using the Synthetic Control Method package **pysyncon** for research. I am trying to create a synthetic Russia to estimate the effect of sanctions on Russia's GDP after 2014, but most of the time the package simply takes the average of all countries in the control donor pool (i.e. assigns equal weights) instead of performing optimization. Does anyone know what the issue could be? See code below.

```
dataprep_test = Dataprep(
    foo=df,
    predictors=["Agriculture, forestry, and fishing, value added (% of GDP)",
                "GDP per capita, PPP (constant 2017 international $)",
                "Industry (including construction), value added (% of GDP)",
                "Inflation, consumer prices (annual %)",
                "Manufacturing, value added (% of GDP)",
                "Net investment in nonfinancial assets (% of GDP)",
                "Oil rents (% of GDP)",
                "Population density (people per sq. km of land area)",
                "School enrollment, tertiary (% gross)",
                "Services, value added (% of GDP)",
                "Total natural resources rents (% of GDP)"],
    predictors_op="mean",
    time_predictors_prior=range(2000, 2014),
    dependent="GDP per capita, PPP (constant 2017 international $)",
    unit_variable="COUNTRY",
    time_variable="YEAR",
    treatment_identifier="Russian Federation",
    controls_identifier=['Albania', 'Algeria', 'Angola', 'Antigua and Barbuda', 'Argentina',
       'Armenia', 'Aruba', 'Australia', 'Azerbaijan', 'Bahamas, The',
       'Bahrain', 'Bangladesh', 'Barbados', 'Belarus', 'Belize', 'Benin',
       'Bermuda', 'Bhutan', 'Bolivia', 'Bosnia and Herzegovina',
       'Botswana', 'Brazil', 'Brunei Darussalam', 'Burkina Faso',
       'Burundi', 'Cabo Verde', 'Cambodia', 'Cameroon', 'Canada',
       'Central African Republic', 'Chad', 'Chile', 'China', 'Colombia',
       'Comoros', 'Congo, Dem. Rep.', 'Congo, Rep.', 'Costa Rica',
       "Cote d'Ivoire", 'Curacao', 'Dominica', 'Dominican Republic',
       'Ecuador', 'Egypt, Arab Rep.', 'El Salvador', 'Equatorial Guinea',
       'Eswatini', 'Ethiopia', 'Fiji', 'Gabon', 'Gambia, The', 'Georgia',
       'Ghana', 'Grenada', 'Guatemala', 'Guinea', 'Guinea-Bissau',
       'Guyana', 'Haiti', 'Honduras', 'Hong Kong SAR, China', 'Iceland',
       'India', 'Indonesia', 'Iran, Islamic Rep.', 'Iraq', 'Israel',
       'Jamaica', 'Japan', 'Jordan', 'Kazakhstan', 'Kenya', 'Kiribati',
       'Korea, Rep.', 'Kuwait', 'Kyrgyz Republic', 'Lao PDR', 'Lebanon',
       'Lesotho', 'Liberia', 'Libya', 'Macao SAR, China', 'Madagascar',
       'Malawi', 'Malaysia', 'Maldives', 'Mali', 'Marshall Islands',
       'Mauritania', 'Mauritius', 'Mexico', 'Micronesia, Fed. Sts.',
       'Moldova', 'Mongolia', 'Montenegro', 'Morocco', 'Mozambique',
       'Myanmar', 'Namibia', 'Nepal', 'New Zealand', 'Nicaragua', 'Niger',
       'Nigeria', 'North Macedonia', 'Norway', 'Oman', 'Pakistan',
       'Palau', 'Panama', 'Papua New Guinea', 'Paraguay', 'Peru',
       'Philippines', 'Puerto Rico', 'Qatar', 'Rwanda', 'Samoa',
       'San Marino', 'Saudi Arabia', 'Senegal', 'Serbia', 'Seychelles',
       'Sierra Leone', 'Singapore', 'Slovak Republic', 'Solomon Islands',
       'South Africa', 'Sri Lanka', 'St. Kitts and Nevis', 'St. Lucia',
       'St. Vincent and the Grenadines', 'Sudan', 'Suriname',
       'Switzerland', 'Tajikistan', 'Tanzania', 'Thailand', 'Timor-Leste',
       'Togo', 'Tonga', 'Trinidad and Tobago', 'Tunisia', 'Turkiye',
       'Turkmenistan', 'Tuvalu', 'Uganda', 'Ukraine',
       'United Arab Emirates', 'Uruguay', 'Uzbekistan', 'Vanuatu',
       'Viet Nam', 'West Bank and Gaza', 'Zambia', 'Zimbabwe'],
    time_optimize_ssr=range(2000,2014),
)

synth = Synth()
synth.fit(dataprep=dataprep_test)
synth.weights()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2D5x.png)

I've tried amending the code in several ways - amending the time range for time_predictors_prior and time_optimize_ssr, reducing the pool of control countries, using penalized synth instead etc. but have not found a solution to this problem.